# How do I reset Kik push token?

Tags: kik

While developing an app I get this response when I try to send a kik push
"Push token is invalid and should be discarded." - 403 status

while on kik docs it's said :
"403: The push token is invalid and should be deleted. Do not attempt to make a push for this token again."

Can I change my push token?
How can I keep developing/test push notification for the current id?

And what triggered the token to become invalid?
(it worked for a while)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually  managed to get a new token by deleting the app from the left menu and accessing it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply generate a new token on the client using:

```
kik.push.getToken(function (token) {
  if (token) {
    // send it to your server
  }
});
```

I'm not sure what made it become invalid but I suspect they simply expire after a set amount of time.